# PYTHON - Flask : 'User' object has no attribute 'is_active'

Tags: python, flask

I have a problem with flask-login. I searched on the site and I have not found the solution...

When I want to connect, I have this message :

AttributeError

AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'is_active'

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__

return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app

response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception

reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app

response = self.full_dispatch_request()

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request

rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception

reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request

rv = self.dispatch_request()

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request

return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)

File "/home/ya2s/UNIVERSITE/WEB/web-serveur/projetvin/tuto/views.py", line 112, in login

login_user(inscrit)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_login.py", line 675, in login_user

if not force and not user.is_active():

AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'is_active'
```

My code in views :

```
from wtforms import PasswordField
from .models import User
from hashlib import sha256

class LoginForm(Form):
    username = StringField('Username')
    password = PasswordField('Password')

    def get_authenticated_user(self):
        user = User.query.get(self.username.data)
        if user is None :
            return None
        m = sha256()
        m.update(self.password.data.encode())
        passwd = m.hexdigest()
        return user if passwd == user.password else None

from flask.ext.login import login_user, current_user
from flask import request

@app.route("/login/", methods=("GET","POST",))
def login():
    f = LoginForm()
    if f.validate_on_submit():
        inscrit = f.get_authenticated_user()
        if inscrit is not None : 
            login_user(inscrit)
            return redirect(url_for("home"))
    return render_template(
        "login.html",
        form = f)
```

My models :

```
from flask.ext.login import UserMixin
from app import login_manager

class User(db.Model):
    username = db.Column(db.String(50), primary_key=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(64))

    def get_id(self):
        return self.username

from .app import login_manager

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(username):
    return User.query.get(username)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `User` class does not define any method `is_active()`. Your user class needs to implement these [documented methods](https://flask-login.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#your-user-class).

Judging by your imports it looks like you had already intended to do it, but you can use the [`UserMixin`](https://flask-login.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#user-object-helpers) class to provide default implementations for the required `User` methods. You should just be able to add `UserMixin` as a base class for your `User` class:

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    username = db.Column(db.String(50), primary_key=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(64))

    def get_id(self):
        return self.username
```

Answer (score 2):

Your User class is missing methods that flask-login expects. Flask-login provides a UserMixin, which you are importing but not using.

Change `class User(db.Model):` to `class User(db.Model, UserMixin):`. You can read about the expected methods [in the docs](https://flask-login.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#your-user-class).

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example implementation of Flask-Login which helped me resolve all doubts: [Flask-admin](https://github.com/mrjoes/flask-admin/blob/master/examples/auth/app.py), please look at line 37, where is_active() is a developer defined function.

Here's snapshot of what I was referring to:

```
# Create user model.
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(100))
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(100))
    login = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120))
    password = db.Column(db.String(64))

    # Flask-Login integration
    def is_authenticated(self):
        return True

    def is_active(self): # line 37
        return True

    def is_anonymous(self):
        return False

    def get_id(self):
        return self.id

    # Required for administrative interface
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.username
```

Comment: Link-only answers are bad as the link may not always exist. In this case, you are referencing a line number in the `master` branch. Changes to the file could result in the contents of the line being different in the future.

Comment: took a snapshot over, but really the file in master is a reference for flask-login integration.